# function global/local variable update issues

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, global-variables

Can someone point out why this function is not outputting? Please explain and give examples. I am just unable to figure out the issue.

```
def double(lst):

    count=0
    result='Found'
    lsy=[count,result]

    for i in lst:
        word=i
        if 'mm' in word:
            result='Found'
            count=0
            break
        if 'nn' in word:
            result='None'
            count+=1

    return lsy

double(['Ammy','Timmy','Jimmy'])
```

Comment: `print(double(['Ammy', 'Timmy', 'Jimmy'])` ? Use the result

Comment: An output needs a call to "print" or something similar.

Comment: OMG. That is really silly of me. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
result = double(['Ammy','Timmy','Jimmy'])
print(result)
# [0, 'Found']
```

Answer (score 0):

use `print()` on your function call. Otherwise nothing is given to stdout, hence why you see nothing.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that the function is producing a wrong result then the problem lies in `lsy` because you do not update it with the `result` after you process the `result` inside the for loop.

If you really meant that you are not getting the output displayed then simply **print** the result:

`print(double(['Ammy', 'Timmy', 'Jimmy']))`